# Reading Excel Files using c#

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

My code for reading excel file is working properly for many of the rows but it doesnt display some contents in the file for e.g(#######) and dates  for e.g (8/11/2009) but  do display dates which have a 2 digit day in it for e.g(11/12/2011).

```
DataTable dtExcel = new DataTable();

string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + HafizwalaFile + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1'";
string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [qe$] ";
OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, excelConnection);

dataAdapter.Fill(dtExcel);
   for (int i = 0; i < dtExcel.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
      for (int j = 0; j < dtExcel.Columns.Count;j++ )
      {
         System.Console.WriteLine(dtExcel.Rows[i][j]);
         count_records++;
      }
   }
```

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing, but to be clear, it is showing dates like '11/11/2013' but **not** '11/8/2013'?

Comment: Usually when you see hashtags in excel its because the column width is too narrow.  Have you expanded the column?

Comment: instead of displaying 10/5/2001 it displays  ,, 37021

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the transfer of data to the table, you have to enter the fileexcel and adjust the worksheet width of this columns are as follows

```
 //using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelapp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
       // excelapp.Visible = true;
        string filename_Path = @"D:\exmp1.xls";
        _Workbook workbook = (_Workbook)(excelapp.Workbooks.Open(filename_Path, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing));



    excelapp .Cells .Columns .AutoFit ();
    workbook.Save();
   // workbook.Close();
    excelapp.Quit();
```

Comment: how to enter the file excel??? how will i access my sheet in the code...as i did above by using a query..

Comment: Do not have access to the file that you are using?
Do you know the name and path?

Comment: Yes setting the width solved my problem i did it manually in the file but how can i do it while programming  idont know the library of worksheet...how to use worksheet.Cells.Columns.AutoFit();? what is the library for it + how to get the worksheet name ?

Comment: thanks you muhammad it did work.. i have to address another problem now after every "date" its displays 12:00:00AM  do you know about this problem? Other wise thanks alot for your help.

Comment: _DateTime date=convert.ToDateTime(dtExcel.Rows[i][j]);_
    _string dateShort = date.ToShortDateString();_
    _System.Console.WriteLine(dateShort );_  @

Comment: Now it keeps giving me this error To save a copy, click OK, then give the workbook a new name in the Save As dialog box how to solve it?plus how can i allow the program to give the file read and write permission?

Comment: Do you want to open the file to edit it manually or from within the application C#?

Comment: actually when i use this command  workbook.Save(); it gives me the above error . by using worksheet.Cells.Columns.AutoFit() it changes the file so i have to save it..through C# application but it gives that error...When ever i open a new file it wont give me the error..plus how can i disable the option do you want to save the changes to file.xls i want my code to automatically do this for me

Comment: يبدو أن هناك حلل ما في اﻷوفيس نفسه ؛ حاول تعمل إصلاح لبرنامج Microspft Office Excel

Comment: Befor close worksheet ; checking if do change for worksheet ; and  did not save this change

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest formatting that column of the excel into date format that forces it to pad 0's or keep it straight text.  I don't think there is anything you can do on the c# side of things

Comment: Is this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

this occurred because you format a column as Date , and you entered data that is not a valid date. you can check this from C# using : 
 `MessageBox.Show(dtExcel.Columns[0].DataType.ToString());` 
Excel stores dates and times as a number representing the number of days since 1900-Jan-0, plus a fractional portion of a 24 hour day:   ddddd.tttttt  [Read this](http://principles.ou.edu/grav_ex/how_excel_stores_dates_and_times.htm)  
 I tried Many times and I find that the following code works fine , (Test it please) :

```
String cellValue = "41577.333333"; // 30/10/2013  8:00:00 AM
            int days  = 0 ;
            int hours = 0;
            string[] arr =  cellValue.Split('.');
            days = int.Parse(arr[0]);
            if(arr.Length == 2)
            {
                decimal  d_hours = decimal.Parse("0." +  arr[1]);
                hours =(int) ( d_hours  * 24  );
            }

            TimeSpan dateFromExcel = new TimeSpan(days ,hours ,0,0,0);
            DateTime resultingDate = new DateTime(1900,1,1 ,0,0,0).Add(dateFromExcel).AddDays(-2);
            MessageBox.Show(resultingDate.ToString());
```

try to use ACE instead of JET , some web sites mentioned this:

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;;Data Source=" + HafizwalaFile + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1'";
```